# Management of notifications in the nopcommerce plugin

Tags: plugins, notifications, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

I develop a plugin on nopcommerce 3.8 and I'm almost at the end. This plugin is the payment plugin and allows to redirect users to a page of a bank to pay the order.
My problem now is to manage the various messages (notifications) that the user will see on our site once an operation has been completed. The transaction may be, payment successful, payment failure, insufficient money in the account, cancellation of payment, etc.
For this, for each operation we must notify the user on our site. For example, after the cancellation of the payment the user is redirected again on our site (Page Index) and we want to show him a message (notification) to tell him that: "You have just canceled your order". In the code of our plugin we have provided the Notify method of our controller which will process the result of each operation. So it is in this method that we want to manage the display of notifications. Here is the beginning of our method.

```
  public ActionResult Notify(WariWebResponse response)
  { 
     //My implementation here
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new { area="" });
  }
```

Comment: And what issue are you facing?

Comment: You can create a view in your plugin and then redirect your customer there. instead of redirecting to home page or you can use email notifications as well

Comment: What was your solution?